# How can I redirect all mails of my smtp server on only one adress mail (using roundcube)?

Tags: server, email, postfix, mail, smtp

I have installed postfix/courier to send and receive mails.

I use roundcube like webmail to watch it.

I have configured postfix with mysql DB, and create `contact@mydomain.com` address. There is possibility to add `alias` in SQL table `alias`, but I don't want to manually add all addresses.

**How can I redirect *root* mails, and `xxxxx@mydomain.com` mails on `contact@mydomain.com`, to be able to watch it with roundcube?**

EDIT:
I found `luser_relay` parameter and [this blog post](http://blog.arithm.com/2008/02/07/postfix-says-recipient-address-rejected-user-unknown-in-local-recipient-table-even-though-youve-set-luser_relay/)

But mail continues to be rejected instead of redirected.

`/usr/sbin/postconf -n`:

```
alias_database               = hash:/etc/aliases  
alias_maps                   = hash:/etc/aliases  
append_dot_mydomain          = no  
biff                         = no  
config_directory             = /etc/postfix  
disable_vrfy_command         = yes  
inet_interfaces              = all  
inet_protocols               = all  
local_recipient_maps         =  
luser_relay                  = contact@localhost  
milter_default_action        = accept  
mydestination                = IP, localhost.localdomain, localhost  
myhostname                   = MYdomain.com  
mynetworks                   = 127.0.0.0/8  
myorigin                     = MYdomain.com   
recipient_delimiter          = +  
relayhost                    =  
smtpd_banner                 = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)  
smtpd_client_restrictions    = permit_mynetworks  
smtpd_helo_required          = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination, reject_non_fqdn_recipient  
smtpd_sender_restrictions    = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_unverified_sender  
virtual_alias_maps           = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_aliases.cf,mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_aliases_comptes.cf  
virtual_gid_maps             = static:5000  
virtual_mailbox_base         = /var/spool/vmail/  
virtual_mailbox_domains      = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domaines.cf  
virtual_mailbox_maps         = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_comptes.cf  
virtual_uid_maps             = static:5000
```

Comment: You will need to do this with your smtp server i.e postfix and not with roundcube. Can you paste the output of `postconf -n` to help you better.

Comment: @clement postconf -n is not a cmd for me. I used the DB of postfix to aliasses mail. But I want redirect all mail sendded to false_adress@mydomain.com to "contact@mydomain.com".

Comment: i didn't get you. You may use DB or any lookup type supported by postfix. your current postfix setting is required to help you on your requirement.`postconf -n` command will give your postfix settings.

Comment: @clement you don't understand me^^ `$ postconf -n` => `-bash: postconf: command not found`. But if there is a parameter to config default adress mail, don't need other things no?

Comment: it should be `/usr/sbin/postconf -n`. Can u check if this works?

Comment: @clement I found thaht: http://blog.arithm.com/2008/02/07/postfix-says-recipient-address-rejected-user-unknown-in-local-recipient-table-even-though-youve-set-luser_relay/ but not working, it's alwais rejected mail to bad adress. (I reload and restartpostfix). I edit my post for config

Comment: Can u paste the entire loglines generated by postfix?

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to add all addresses you can just add an alias from '@mydomain.com' to 'contact@mydomain.com', but please note that with this parameter every possible mail to any e-mail address is forwarded also if the address is not added into the mailbox maps. So you also receive also spam to all of this addresses.